# Make a variable if file exists in Java?

Tags: java

So I have this code,

```
static File overlay1 = new File(Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir, "\\TVMod\\Pictures\\" + pictureList[0].getName());
```

But when I run that code I get a NullPointerException becuase pictureList[0] doesnt exist. But I want it to make the variable only if pictureList[0] exists. I hope I explaned this well

Comment: Check if `pictureList[0] != null`?

Comment: It probably shouldn't be in a `static` field initialization.

Comment: *Making* variables based on a condition cannot work. How would you *use* it? Always create the variable, but set it to `Null` (or the nearest Java equivalent) if its value is not set.

Comment: How could you start programming without learning about `if`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 static{
        if (pictureList != null && pictureList.length>0)
            overlay1 = new File(Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir, "\\TVMod\\Pictures\\" + pictureList[0].getName());
    }
 static File overlay1;
```